# How to add 240v sub-panel from meter main lug of 1950's

Tags: subpanel, 120-240v

Current meter main lug (100A), which is at outdoor, goes to a sub-panel inside house. I want to add a sub-panel (240v), which is also at outside, from the main lug.

One option is to replace the meter panel, which I am trying to avoid.

Another option to extend current connector with new lug nuts which has extensions.  I have not done it yet, and not sure it is possible, in terms of if it's going to fit. With this option, I can switch off without asking PGE to cut off the power, and adding the "extension" which may be possible.

My question is if 2nd options is feasible? Any risk? Any suggestion? The extension lug nut is what I could find. Not sure if there is other options.

Also, I am not sure if existing connector can be removed and replaced. If NOT, is it possible to use aluminum 'bar' which can be bought at Home Depot to make it, so that it can be inserted into existing hole?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I take it the existing subpanel is stuffed to the gills already?

Answer (score 2):

Bite the bullet. Upgrade.

If any of these "double lug" options are actually permitted, you are still limited to 100A total. You have a 200A meter. You can pretty definitely get 200A service. You *may* even already have 200A-capable wires going from the meter to the pole. If you add stuff, which is the whole point of another subpanel, plus properly calculate the existing stuff (I'd be willing to be you have more things in your existing subpanel than you did when the house was built), you will very possibly go over 100A **Load Calculation**.

You're playing with fire. Literally.

I know it is a pain, but it should not be a huge expense (relatively speaking) to:

- Replace the meter + one-breaker "main" with a "meter main" that has a place for the meter and a small (e.g., 8 spaces is plenty) panel.

*or*

- Keep the meter in its existing place and add a small 200A panel (200A main breaker, 100A for each subpanel feed) below it.

You will also, unless it is hiding somewhere in the picture, have to get your ground wire/ground rods redone.

Start with a Load Calculation for old + new. If that is actually under 100A then you can consider double-lugs, etc. If it is > 100A then you really need to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need 200A. 100A should be ok as I already calculated. I want to add sub-panel with 240v, not 200v. I know 100A should be within limit of usage. Yes. the ground is in current main lug, which does not shown clearly. So, my original question is how to do it safely with 2nd option if possible.

Comment: If not playing with extension lug, and avoiding replacing existing main lug panel, 3rd possible option is to remove existing sub-panel wire from the switch, and wire it out to new sub-panel, where to add 240v 30A breaker for EV charge, and 100A breaker (not exist at present. safer?) for existing sub-panel and wire it back to exiting main lug and connect it to existing sub-panel wires inside existing main lug. Any comments on which option may be better?

Comment: Nowhere in the US are you going to get 200 volts except _maybe_ in some sort of specialty application, most likely at a factory or lab. Nothing off the shelf will support it, so don't worry,@user3792705, you'll get 240 volts. The only question is 100 or 200 _amps_.

Comment: @user3792705 this answer makes good suggestions.  If you are working on the main switch outside and installing a new panel, you shouldn't design the new system based on your own immediate needs.   It costs very little more to install a more versatile system that may serve your future needs or make the house more valuable.   You haven't told us what kind of building this is or what electrical loads you have, but modernizing a house with two subpanels and 100A total is not typical or intuitive, so for the best answers you should go with the advice above or provide more info.

Comment: That said, the Question is not unreasonable.  There are ways to split a feed, and the gizmo in the question may or may not be acceptable.  So perhaps this answer should be a brief comment.

Comment: If I really wanted to upgrade this setup without replacing the main shutoff - and I'm with this answer, you really should - I'd install a new 200A panel hanging off this 100A breaker and then connect the existing panel to a 100A breaker off the new panel. When it comes time to finish the upgrade to a 200A meter main, everything new would still be usable.

Comment: I would go with 1) this answer, 2) @KMJ suggestion 3) if you insist on doing it as proposed use 3-port Polaris rather than trying to figure out if your 1950s switch can directly accommodate weird piggyback lugs, presuming you do not have its documentation.  That's a very distant #3.

Comment: You have 100A service/panel/etc. right now. You are **adding** 30A for EV (which is reasonable). But that gets count 100% with respect to Load Calculation because it can be running several hours at a time while cooking, HVAC and everything else is running. So the question then is: **What is the Load Calculation for everything else already connected?** If that is less than 70A then you are OK. If it is greater than 70A, *which is quite possible*, then you simply can't do this without a heavy-up. In my case, I went for a heavy-up even though I am still under 100A (and still no EV, sadly)

Comment: because I wanted all the other benefits (new panel, generator interlock, etc.). But it is called a heavy-up because the basic reason is to increase the amount of power, *and I really think you may need that.*

Comment: @jay613 has the guidance for if you really want to do this goofy plan: use Polaris connectors rather than trying to modify the lugs. The serves as a junction box and should have enough cubic inches to hold the appropriate connectors. You absolutely can not modify the lugs yourself with random Home Depot aluminum.